# Subtract a value before sumifs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to subtract a certain value before adding it together with sumifs. Made a simple example of what I want to do: see picture

[image]

Comment: for criteria1 its sumif of (7-1)+(3-1)+(2-1) = 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following formula:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$7,D2,$B$2:$B$7)-COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,D2)*E2
```

[image]